# Hugo: override theme title generation for a page

Tags: hugo

I am using a theme where the page's title is generated in this way (snippet from the theme `layout/partials/head/metadata.html`):

```
<title>
{{ .Title | humanize | title }}{{ if ne .Title .Site.Title }} - {{ .Site.Title | markdownify }}{{ end }}
</title>
```

The problem is the `humanize` function: I have a page in my site where the title is something like `A-Foobar etc etc` and it renders the title like  `A Foobar` because the humanize removes the `-`.

There is some way to resolve this ?  A way to change how the title is generated for a specific page?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this

```
<title>
    {{ with .Params.override_Title }}
      {{ . | title }}
    {{ else }}
      {{ .Title | humanize | title }}{{ if ne .Title .Site.Title }} - {{ .Site.Title | markdownify }}{{ end }}
    {{ end }}
</title>
```

Then in your front matter of a page put in (depends if it's toml/yaml whatever):

```
override_Title: 'My new override title'
```

This means - if you have the front matter set where you want an override it uses that  ELSE it uses this metadata guys normal setup...

Comment: Note: Generally it's not a good idea to edit a theme, you should just ask the theme maker to update his code...

Comment: Ok but the main point of my question is to override the theme I am using and its settings, not to modify it.

Comment: That would be directed towards the theme creator who I assume has contact data - up to you to find or a github account etc etc  etc... The above is the code to handle the problem, how the theme was made - that's a particular implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Hugo as an embed lookup order that allows to customize a theme without changing the theme's templates, as it priorizes the site's templates over the theme's templates.

The reference is here:
https://gohugo.io/templates/lookup-order/

In your case, if you have:

`/themes/THEME_NAME/layout/partials/head/metadata.html`

you can copy paste the `metadata.html` in your site `layout/partials/head/` directory, and it will have priority over the theme file. Then, you can tweak the file to suits your needs. Make sure it is the exact same directory structure inside layout, otherwise Hugo won't override the theme file.

`/layout/partials/head/metadata.html`